# Roslyn - Is symbol implementation of interface?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to know with Roslyn if a Symbol is the implementation of something in an interface? For example `Dispose()` in `IDisposable`?

I have a symbol that represents the `Dispose()` method, but as far as I can see there is no property that indicates that it's an implementation of a method that is defined by the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: That is actually not easy, and - depending on your interpretation - even impossible for public types. For more information, see the source code for [FindImplementedInterfaceMembersAsync](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder_Hierarchy.cs,2ff44ec7ffcdbeaf). Notice the comment: "A method may implement an interface method, even if its containing type doesn't state that it implements the interface."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure its possible.

Just for your `Dispose` example:

```
var disposeMethodSymbol = ...
var type = disposeMethodSymbol.ContainingType;
var isInterfaceImplementaton = type.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(
            type.Interfaces.Single().
            GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>().Single()) == disposeMethodSymbol ;
```

But if it for general use you need to write it more generally, use `AllInterfaces` and not `Interfaces` and sure not use `Single`.

Example:

```
public static bool IsInterfaceImplementation(this IMethodSymbol method)
{
    return method.ContainingType.AllInterfaces.SelectMany(@interface => @interface.GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>()).Any(interfaceMethod => method.ContainingType.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(interfaceMethod).Equals(method));
}
```

Comment: Beware that this will not work properly with generic interfaces.

Comment: @SLaks how can we let this work properly with generic interfaces as well?

Answer (score 4):

You may find useful this set of extension methods from Roslyn:
http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/ISymbolExtensions.cs,93

Particularly this one `ExplicitOrImplicitInterfaceImplementations` method:

```
public static ImmutableArray<ISymbol> ExplicitOrImplicitInterfaceImplementations(this ISymbol symbol)
{
    if (symbol.Kind != SymbolKind.Method && symbol.Kind != SymbolKind.Property && symbol.Kind != SymbolKind.Event)
        return ImmutableArray<ISymbol>.Empty;

    var containingType = symbol.ContainingType;
    var query = from iface in containingType.AllInterfaces
                from interfaceMember in iface.GetMembers()
                let impl = containingType.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(interfaceMember)
                where symbol.Equals(impl)
                select interfaceMember;
    return query.ToImmutableArray();
}
```

Comment: In which nuget package/version does this method exist?

Comment: Just realized that all of these extensions are internal and cannot be used directly

Comment: FindImplementationForInterfaceMember() does the trick